# Click on xy of a webpage using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

Automating logging into homeroom everyday, the teacher posts a new link to meets everyday but the link is always in the same position on the screen. I cant simply find element by xpath, id, class etc... This is why I figured if I could simply click on certain coordinates my problem would be solved but im having trouble doing this in selenium. Im fairly new to python though and im sure theres something ive missed, any bright ideas?

Comment: Your code trials?

Answer (score 1):

Can actually not comment your question directly, cause of reputation - Would be great to show some code you have written or going more in to detail.

**Just a hint ActionChains**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'), 0,0)
actions.move_by_offset(X coordinates, Y coordinates).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html).

You can `pip install` it, then add `pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)` in your Selenium script.